# unexpected behavior in storefront

Tags: magento2

I've recently start working on implemented storefront that was developed by others, and I just solving bugs.

2 days ago I've noticed unexpected behavior in checkout for example:

-checkbox for using default address for shipping and billing not working. I click it but no change happen

-shipping options disappeared

what are causes

Comment: Did you check for JS error or any type of error in console ? If yes then please paste the error here

Comment: @ShubhamMathur I've found syntax error but I cannot get page url to check it as it contains security info. do you know how can I get its url?

Comment: @ShubhamMathur error is solved but I still get same behavior

Comment: Please provide the screenshots and code dump if possible (for the changes you have made)